# DLL load failed while importing cdmapi: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x

Found Amazon-video-downloader at [GitHub](https://github.com/dimqua/Amazon-video-downloader) and followed the instructions as given in How.To.Use.txt. However, its not working. Error log from command prompt is given below. Why DLL loading failed? What module is missing? How to make it work?

```
C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader>amazon.py -r us -p us -a B08BYZKJSH
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\amazon.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyamazon.asin_handler import Amazon
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\pyamazon\asin_handler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyamazon.Downloader import AmazonDownloader as downloader
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\pyamazon\Downloader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pyamazon.Decrypt.Amazon import AmazonDecrypt
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\pyamazon\Decrypt\Amazon.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pyamazon.Decrypt.wvdecrypt import WvDecrypt
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\pyamazon\Decrypt\wvdecrypt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pyamazon.Decrypt.cdm import cdm, deviceconfig
  File "C:\Users\vbox\Downloads\Amazon-video-downloader\pyamazon\Decrypt\cdm\cdm.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyamazon.Decrypt.cdm import cdmapi
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cdmapi: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.